# “Ich geht es gut“ or “Mir geht es gut“

Tags: grammatical-case

I am learning about *dative*, *nominative*, and *accusative*. I have seen the following two expressions:

> - Ich geht es gut.
> - Mir geht es gut.

Accordung to *Google Translate* both are right. But I doubt a little, so are these answers right?

Comment: May I ask what sentence exactly it was that Google translated as »Ich geht es gut«?

Comment: I thought I could find one, but Google is smarter than me and translates even "ich is fine" to "mir geht es gut" :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wem geht es gut?

> Mir geht es gut.

You need to use **Dativ** here. *Wem* asks for *Dativ*.

The other phrase is wrong. Google translate is never a good source and should be used only to get a rough direction.

Comment: The trick with *asking* for something to find the needed case works quite well for native speakers. There's proof it doesn't work at all for all the others.

Comment: I know. Can't work if you neither use *wem* automatically nor know what case you should ask for. It wasn't meant as a "trick" here. ;)

Comment: @tofor: Indeed. I am not a native speakee, but have been speaking German fror more than 35 years now and even understood it as a small kid. The "wem", "wen" etc. question never helped me.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase you picked isn't simple. It's a use of *gehen* which isn't relation to the action of walking at all. There's no logic in the highly idiomatic uses either:

> Es geht.

*It works.*

> Es geht nicht.

*It doesn't work.*

> Es geht (ganz) gut.

*It works (quite) well.*

> Es geht (ganz) schlecht.

*It works (very) bad.*

If you used an additional object to tell who's meant, it has to be a dative object, because it's not a thing or person acted upon (that would call for an accusative object).

> Es geht ihm gut.

*He is fine.*

Answer (score 1):

In your examples, only the second option is correct. This particular use of the verb *gehen* belongs to a group of verbs where the **experiencer** of a feeling or sensation is not expressed in the nominative case, even though he is the logical subject of the sentence. Here are some other verbs that behave similarly:

> **Mir** ist schlecht. **Mir** wird kalt. **Mir** scheint, dass es kälter wird. *(Dative)*
>
> **Mich** friert es. **Mich** schaudert es. *(Accusative)*

Comment: Im Satz »Mir geht es gut« = »Es geht mir gut« ist das expletive Pronomen *»es«* das Subjekt. *»Mir« ist ein ganz normales Dativ-Objekt (Dativus Commodi). Die von dir genannten Sätze folgen einer anderen Konstruktion als der Satz aus der Frage.

Comment: Ich habe allerdings vom _logischen_ Subjekt gesprochen, nicht vom _grammatischen_ Scheinsubjekt _es_. Und inwiefern folgen meine Beispiele bitte einer anderen Konstruktion?